# Question on C^1 functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose $x_{0} \in R^n$ and $0\leq r_{1}< r_{2}$. Show that there exists a $C^1$ function  $f:R^n \to R$ such that $f(x)=0$ for $||x-x_{0}||\geq r_{2}$; $0 <f (x)<1$ for $r_{1}<||x-x_{0}||<r_{2}$; and $f (x)=1$ for $||x-x _{0}||\leq r_{1}$

Comment: Does [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) help you?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making it radially symmetric, which would reduce the problem to finding such a function on $\mathbb{R}$. Then try finding a polynomial that will satisfy the conditions that you want between $r_1$ and $r_2$.